# Calculating empirical formula of vitamin C

Tags: organic-chemistry, homework

Combustion of 0.2000 g of vitamin C gives 0.2998 g $\ce{CO2}$ and 0.819 g of water. What is the empirical formula of vitamin C?

My work:

I calculated moles of products and found the mole ratio but it's not coming to be a whole number.

Comment: We cannot answer homework questions. Would you mind sharing more of your work and thought process though so we can better assist you?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong number for the grams of water, it should be 0.0819.  Go back and redo your calculations with that change.  Now you should get the correct ratio of the elements in the molecular formula for ascorbic acid.  If you don't, report back and show your math.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the mole ratios but they are not whole numbers, divide through by the smallest number. Say you get for some hypothetical compound the following formula:

${C_{2.5}H_{5}O_{7.5}}$

In this case to get the empirical formula, just divide each subscript by 2.5, the smallest subscript. You will get:

${CH_{2}O_{3}}$